# Contiguous Printing in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have developed a Crystal report (more like modified a default one that came with Epicor) that prints out parts and descriptions on a sales order.  At our company, we have a generic part number that is representative of a particular type of finished product.  In the description, we provide detailed information on the specific product being supplied, like sizes and various other specifications.  As a result, these descriptions can get pretty lengthy.  The problem is that Crystal prints the descriptions as a block rather than flowing text.  Meaning that if a description is too large to fit in the remaining space on a page, it will jump it to the next page leaving a large gap on the previous page, instead of printing the text that does fit and then starting over on a new page with the remaining text.  This really causes problems when a description is roughly the same size as a page, as it duplicates the description, sometimes more than a dozen times.  So my question is, is there a way to make Crystal print these as flowing, contiguous text rather than blocks?

Comment: In the section details containing the description field, have you tried unchecking the `Keep Together` option?

Comment: The Keep Together option for the section was cleared, but not on the description field itself.  However, clearing it didn't change anything.