# Suppressing Sections/Fields Using Booleans

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Ok, first, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
I am trying to append a "Terms % Conditions" section to a printout.  I've done this by splitting the report footer up into several sections.  The first section of the report footer contains the actual report footer data (dollar totals and that sort of thing).  The others contain the terms and conditions stuff and are set to create a new page prior to each one.  I have a page header set up, but I don't want all of it to print on the terms and conditions pages so I tried using a boolean variable to determine when the terms and conditions begins to print.  Here's how:
In the report header, I declared and set the variable as such:

```
booleanvar TermsStart;
TermsStart := false;
```

Then in the actual report footer (with the dollar totals) I set it to true because the report itself is done and all that's left is the terms section:

```
booleanvar TermsStart;
TermsStart := true;
```

Now, in the header sections I wrote the following to try suppressing the unwanted sections:

```
booleanvar TermsStart;
TermsStart;
```

It didn't suppress when it should have, so I printed out the TermsStart variable in several sections throughout the report and in every single place it prints false, even in the same section where I set it to true.  The formula field that sets it true does actually print true, but the variable doesn't seem to change or somehow gets reset.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. The reason it's not suppressing the header is because in the header section, the variable is still "false", whereas in the footer it is "true". So if you put a suppress in the header on the condition of "true", it will fail. 
I suggest that you try this maybe with page numbers instead. I'm not sure how your report is structured, but you can use TotalPageCount. A suppression statement like `PageNumber <> TotalPageCount` will suppress your Terms & Conditions until the last page, and `PageNumber = TotalPageCount` will suppress the Header on the last page.

Comment: I originally tried using `pagenumber < totalpagecount-3` (terms is 3 pages) but there is another problem (one I [posted about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052925/contiguous-printing-in-crystal-reports) a while back) that was making it 4 pages and throwing me off.  I still haven't fixed the other issue but the totalpagecount seems to work for this one.

Comment: That said, you say that the reason it doesn't work is because the header is resolved first and the variable is not set to true until the footer which is why the conditional to suppress the header fails.  This makes sense, but what doesn't make sense then, is that in the _same_ section where it is set to true and in every footer section after that, why does printing the variable still show false?

Comment: Is there any way to attach files to a post?  I could attach a copy of the report to show you what I mean.

Comment: Well, I think the way you wrote your formulas isn't quite right, either. I tried it on a sample report and used  'shared booleanvar TermsStart; TermsStart := false;' and 'shared booleanvar TermsStart; TermsStart := true;' in two seperate formulas. I put the "false" in the header and the "true" in the  report footers. The error I believe is in the formula where you try and show the value: it should be 'shared booleanvar TermsStart; TermsStart'. So leave the ";" out on the last line and try it again.

Comment: Well, you were right.  My formula wasn't quite right.  The semicolon didn't make a difference, but I did notice you were using shared and I was using a global variable.  Once I changed it to a shared variable, everything worked (including the formulas to suppress the header)!  Thanks for your help!